# Trouble exporting using create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to use `create-react-app` for the first time to start a project, but I'm having trouble. It seems my component is not being exported because I keep getting this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

The code for component I'm trying to render looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {};
}

export const HomePage = connect(mapStateToProps)(
    class HomePageComponent extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    hi
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
)
```

I'm using it here

```
import { HomePage } from './Frontend/Components/HomePage.tsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HomePage/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

which is hooked into the html here

```
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the further error message? It usually says: `check out the render method of ...`

Comment: Check the render method of `App`. Which only renders `HomePage` so I don't understand what is wrong with the way I am exporting `HomePage`

Comment: So what will log: `import { HomePage } from './Frontend/Components/HomePage.tsx';  console.log(HomePage);` ?

Comment: It is `undefined` but how can this be when I'm obviously exporting something.